# Is there a way to export what "where is this used?" details?

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow, metadata, fields, data-export

I'm trying to collect and analyze field metadata. It would be extremely helpful if there was a way to mass export (e.g. all account fields) with the details around where the fields are used (same view as the "where is this used?" button presents for each field. I can export various aspects of metadata, but I'm unsure if there is a way to have a view same as the "where is this used?" shows... Is there a way to do that?

Alternatively, what is the way to export fields used in processes / workflow / flows?

thank you so much for the help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "Dependencies API" feature. You can query the [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) object to determine, for example, every component that depends on a specific field. You can also independently export Flows and Workflow Rules, and then do a search across all files (most IDEs provide this sort of function; check the online help). Refer to the documentation for specific information on the queries you can use.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I did more research, now knowing what to learn more about and managed to get all data I needed. Thank you again.